# The field JsonHttpParser.jsonFactory is not visible

Tags: android

Im developing an application that simply shows the nearby places to my location and i have implemented the map layout and got my location. i have used this blog http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html

in order to retrieve the places nearby but there is one problem i cant solve in this method

private static final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp
            .newCompatibleTransport();
public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final HttpTransport transport) {

```
    return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
    GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
    headers.setApplicationName("Google-Places-DemoApp");
    request.setHeaders(headers);
    JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser();
    parser.jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    request.addParser(parser);
    }
    });
    }
```

which simply does open an http connection to execute the search url

the problem is that at parser.jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory(); eclipse tell me that The field JsonHttpParser.jsonFactory is not visible. how can i solve this issue knowing that i have imported all necessary external jars.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem before.

This is because the **jsonFactory and headers variables are depracated since 1.6**. If you are using Google APIs before 1.6 version, it should work properly.

Check this for more info:

1. http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/http-client/google-http-client/1.5.0-beta/google-http-client-1.5.0-beta-javadoc.jar!/com/google/api/client/http/json/JsonHttpParser.html#jsonFactory
2. http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.5.0-beta/com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequest.html

You need to devise alternate methods to be used.

Use the below re-framed code:

```
GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
headers.setApplicationName("Google-Places-DemoApp");
request.setHeaders(headers);

request.addParser(new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory()));
```

Note: Not tested!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Class JsonHttpParser and Method HttpRequest were both deprecated in version 1.11. See [The Deprecated list](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.10.2-beta/deprecated-list.html) for more information.

So instead of:

```
            JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser();
            parser.jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            request.addParser(parser);
```

Try:

```
            JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.setParser(parser);
```

And use import:

```
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser;
```

Note: Not tested.